# Is there any way to render tablix from right to left in SSRS 2012

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

Is there any way to render a tablix from right to left in SSRS 2012?

Rather than Layout Direction rtl it's a case of reordering Columns

I have matrix with dynamic columns.  I want to render it from right to left

Comment: Did you try sorting in the `Column Groups >> Group Properties >> Sorting`? If you sort the column `Z to A` then it will reorder.